# iOS - Floating cursor with input elements inside flexbox

Tags: html, css, ios7, flexbox

Has anyone addressed the floating cursor issue with input elements that are inside flexbox layouts in HTML apps on iOS7?

Go to http://cdn.sencha.com/touch/sencha-touch-2.3.1a/built-examples/kitchensink/index.html#demo/formpanel, focus on an input element, and scroll.

I've seen this same behavior on several different HTML mobile frameworks.  It seems flexbox is the culprit.  Any workarounds?

[image: cursor floating during scroll]

Comment: Not sure if this helps but I encountered this problem and was fixed using this solution - `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, target-densityDpi=device-dpi" />`

Comment: I'll give it a shot, but I've seen the issue on demo pages that have the viewport tag specified.

Comment: In my case `target-densityDpi=device-dpi"` did the trick on me I think.

Comment: @AndyEdinborough Ever find an answer to this?  I am experiencing the same issue (iOS 8.3).  `target-densityDpi=device-dpi` doesn't seem to be supported.

Comment: @Mike_G Unfortunately no, I haven't.  Instead I started working on my own framework that didn't use flexbox.

Comment: I get this issue in iOS8.4 too

Comment: have you tried removing the padding from the input and just align the text inside it with line-height only? I had a similar problem, and that did the trick for me

Comment: Flexbox isn't great for *many* things. Maybe it's best to use floats for inputs? Really glad to know about this issue though -

Comment: Does this link could help ? https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs

Answer (score 1):

It's a known bug and its reported by many users...

WebKit bug: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=138201
Apple Radar: http://openradar.appspot.com/18819624

There is no known workaround as of now...

Update: Was fixed in iOS 8.3